# Поменять стиль тэга

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify

Хочу поменять стили для тэга `vuetify v-data-table`. Как мне обратиться к `:headers="dataSecretsTableHeaders"`, если я хочу поменять стили только для `dataSecretsTableHeaders` в `CSS`?

```html
<div class="table">
  <v-data-table :headers="dataSecretsTableHeaders" :items="dataSecrets" :items-per-page="7" class="table">
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        edit
      </v-icon>
      <v-icon
        small
        @click="deleteItem(item)"
      >
        delete
      </v-icon>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.button="{ item }">
      <button
        class='button-secondary'
        @click="goTo(`/data-secrets/analytics/${item.id}`,item)"
      >
        View Analytics
      </button>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</div>
```

P.S. Не нужно писать , что стили задаются для тега , а не для атрибута. Внимательнее прочитайте вопрос =)

Comment: Я же вам писал, что код инспектировать надо!

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо просто проинспектировать код через консоль. Предположу, что вы не знали об этом. Вызывается комбинацией клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> или <kbd>F12</kbd> (`Chrome`). Выполнив команды вы увидите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видим, что :headers превращается в `.v-data-table-header`. Дописываем стиль.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      expand: false,
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        },
        {
          text: 'Carbs (g)',
          value: 'carbs'
        },
        {
          text: 'Protein (g)',
          value: 'protein'
        },
        {
          text: 'Iron (%)',
          value: 'iron'
        }
      ],
      desserts: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.v-data-table-header{
  user-select: none;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </template>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.*/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

> `:headers` - динамический атрибут.